# Swift Mailer - send emails asynchronnously

Tags: php, email, asynchronous, swiftmailer

on a project with intensive emailing activity we are creating asynchronnous workflow for posting emails. Workflow consists of 2 steps:

1. creating the message (we set Subject, From, to, body, attachments), then converting to a string via `$mailer->toString()` and store into database.
2. get few latest emails from database and send them out to user(s).

String stored into database is actually valid multipart EML file (e.g. can be open with Outlook) with message headers + body.

QUESTION:

**How can I send message converted toString via SwiftMailer using it's transport capabilities?**

Thank you.

Example of stored string in the database:

```
Message-ID: <1803a1a74c7612e43d58a8ca558117f3@refactoring.local>
Date: Mon, 16 Oct 2017 13:50:31 +0200
Subject: Sample subject
From: info@refactoring.local
Reply-To: info@refactoring.local
To: aaa@bbb.cc
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1508154632_faf5d3b80866048d993d77a62a9e6497_=_"

--_=_swift_v4_1508154632_faf5d3b80866048d993d77a62a9e6497_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

sample body ...

--_=_swift_v4_1508154632_faf5d3b80866048d993d77a62a9e6497_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org=
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
=09<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8"=
 />
=09<title>Sample title</title>
=09</head>
<body>
=09=09

=09sample body ...
=09</body>
</html>

--_=_swift_v4_1508154632_faf5d3b80866048d993d77a62a9e6497_=_--
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Dbl0McJim Unfortunately, no. We had to go back to old good PhpMailer (actually not so old, it's well maintained and has much lower memory footprint) which allows fetching email body in pure text via method `$mailer->PreSend()`. It was actually quite easy. We dont have to worry that some class changed for emails queued for few months ..

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to convert a with `toString` serialized message back to an `Swift_Message`. Instead, you should use the `serialize` function to convert the `Swift_Message` you want to store inside the database back to an string.

```
$data = serialize($message);
// store inside database
// ...
// later..
$message = unserialize($message);
$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: We don't need to convert it back, of course :-) Just to send out fully qualified valid email message. We have everything needed for posting - `email to` and SMTP `authorization credentials`. Previous solution with PHPMailer worked easily this way. We are trying to move from PHPMailer to more RFC compliant library. Serialization is definitely not preferred since objects may change any time.